# Errors wrapping root element with Provider when converting to TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a side project which I decided to convert to TS from JS. It's a React project using Redux.

I'm encountering a problem when trying to wrap my root element in Provider. The lines of code giving me the error message are wrapped in three * signs within ReactDOM.render.

Here's the [Github link](https://github.com/davidemmolino/flight-tracker)

The error I'm getting is

```
any
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.ts(2365)
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | DocumentFragment | null'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(93, 5): The last overload is declared here.
'App' refers to a value but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof App'?**strong text**
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './components/App.js';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/flightsReducers';
import store from './store';

// import { styles } from '../public/styles.scss';
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider ***store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>***
    , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Exactly what line of code is reporting this error?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my post accordingly. The error message is within 3 * signs inside the ReactDOM.render method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the app runs fine in the browser (via `npm run dev`) meant that this is an issue with your editor and not the code itself.

By changing the name of **client/index.ts** to **client/index.tsx** the editor will start recognizing your use of JSX and will quiet down the typing issues:

[image: demonstrating file extension tweak fix]